# Apple Health (HealthKit) Request

Tags: testflight, healthkit, applehealth

I am making an app that collects information from Apple Health (HealthKit). When the application is installed for the first time, the apple screen appears with the permissions that will be used, but when it is in Testflight that screen never appears, is there any extra configuration that has to be done when it is released to production?

if the app is installed from xcode, it works correctly

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had two different bundles, one both in the card of my app and another service that I have OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension. Within both they must point to release and not to debug. that's what i did and it worked in testFlight

Comment: The same case happened to me also. After checking we found that there are two bundle Ids are used, for the test flight builds, the healthkit capability was not enabled which was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I confirmed this worked.  It's in signing and capabilities.  You have to re-add healthkit again and then you get the release.  It combined both of them to form just health kit!   I've been rejected because the app reviewers can't see me using the heart monitor portion of my app.